# center aligning text to the right of a floating div

Tags: html, css

I want to create three divs that are small boxes that are colored respectively:

```
<div class="foo blue"></div>Blue
<div class="foo purple"></div>Purple
<div class="foo wine"></div>Wine

.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.blue {
  background: #13b4ff;
}

.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}

.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

This works for everything except I need the text next to each box to align to the right of its respective div. Everything should be in one row, with the text vertically aligned to its div. This just forces text outside the confines of the three divs. What's the appropriate way to wire it together?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vsfu72j8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `float:left` to:

```
.foo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

here is the fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsfu72j8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

With flexbox, use `inline-flex` along with `align-items: center;`, but first you need to wrap your elements in another tag.

**Code Snippet:**

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.foo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.blue {
  background: #13b4ff;
}
.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}
.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="foo blue"></span> Blue
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="foo purple"></span> Purple
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="foo wine"></span> Wine
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

You can also improve this semantically, using an SVG `<rect>` to represent your squares. Using a spritesheet to reuse the same element.

**Code Snippet:**

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.foo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.blue {
  color: #13b4ff;
}
.purple {
  color: #ab3fdd;
}
.wine {
  color: #ae163e;
}
.svg-spritesheet {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <svg class="foo blue">
      <use xlink:href="#foo"></use>
    </svg>
    Blue
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg class="foo purple">
      <use xlink:href="#foo"></use>
    </svg>
    Purple
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg class="foo wine">
      <use xlink:href="#foo"></use>
    </svg>
    Wine
  </li>
</ul>

<svg class="svg-spritesheet">
  <symbol id="foo" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <title>foo</title>
    <rect width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" stroke="#000" stroke-opacity="0.2" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to rearrange your HTML structure a little bit. I've used **CSS Flexbox** to achieve your requirements.

Please have a look at the below code or checkout this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vsfu72j8/3/).

Learn more about [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.item-holder {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.foo {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.blue {
  background: #13b4ff;
}

.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}

.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-holder">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="foo blue"></div>
    <div class="text">Blue</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="foo purple"></div>
    <div class="text">Purple</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="foo wine"></div>
    <div class="text">Wine</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you want your divs to behave like a table you can define so using CSS. I find it very intuitive and handful for some situations:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table-row">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <div class="foo blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">Blue</div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <div class="foo purple"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">Purple</div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <div class="foo wine"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">Wine</div>
</div>
```

Notice how the divs are nested as a table structure.

**CSS**

```
.table-row{   
    display:table-row; 
} 

.table-cell{   
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.foo {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   margin: 5px;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.blue {
     background: #13b4ff; 
}

.purple {
    background: #ab3fdd; 
}

.wine {
    background: #ae163e; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xzj6eauf/